# Changing an array to lower case

Tags: javascript, arrays

Create an Array of Drinks with all capital letters

```js
var drinks = ["Coke", "Pepsi", "Water", "Orange Juice"];

console.log("First statement");
console.log(drinks[0]);
console.log(drinks[1]);
console.log(drinks[2]);
console.log(drinks[3]);
```

Then modify each element of the array (individually) to make them lowercase

Comment: Do you need to mutate the original array?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like below. This basically goes through each element in the array, and uses [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to change the string to a lowercase string.

```js
var drinks = ["Coke", "Pepsi", "Water", "Orange Juice"];

var lowerCaseDrinks = drinks.map(e => e.toLowerCase());

console.log(lowerCaseDrinks);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to mutate the original array, you can use the function `forEach` to loop and modify each index value.

```js
var drinks = ["Coke", "Pepsi", "Water", "Orange Juice"];
drinks.forEach((s, i, arr) => arr[i] = s.toLowerCase());
console.log(drinks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var drinks = ["Coke", "Pepsi", "Water", "Orange Juice"].map(v => v.toLowerCase());
console.log(drinks);
```

or use this code because arrow functions will not work at all in IE :

```js
var drinks = ["Coke", "Pepsi", "Water", "Orange Juice"].map(function(v) {
  return v.toLowerCase();
});
console.log(drinks);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it **immutably**, which is without modifying the original array, use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get a transformed array, and [`String.toLocaleLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) to lowercase your items:

```js
const drinks = ["Coke", "Pepsi", "Water", "Orange Juice"];

const result = drinks.map(x => x.toLocaleLowerCase());
console.log(result);
```

Otherwise, for a **mutable way to do it**, use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const drinks = ["Coke", "Pepsi", "Water", "Orange Juice"];

drinks.forEach((x, i, arr) => arr[i] = x.toLocaleLowerCase());
console.log(drinks);
```